Get non-used GitHub Copilot licenses in an organization by API
Does anyone know how to get all GitHub Copilot licenses including the non-activated GitHub Copilot by API?
If someone also knows how to get only the licenses that haven't been activated, I'll be happy to hear that.
This API call:
"/orgs/{org}/copilot/billing/seats"
gives only the details about activated licenses.
Thanks a lot!
